# Assigning a value from a text file to variable in shell in loop

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, unix, do-loops

I have text file, which will contain 1 record and more. I need to assign each row values of a column to a variable during each loop
for example :

test.txt:

```
1234,12,IN,John,xyz@hotmail.com
1111,10,SA,John,xyz@hotmail.com
2222,11,EU,John,xyz@hotmail.com
3333,13,CN,John,xyz@hotmail.com
4444,14,US,John,xyz@hotmail.com
```

Delete statement :

```
delete from table1.test where id=$var1 and code=$var2 and country='$var3'
```

loop 1 - delete query will use the below variable values

```
$var1=1234, $var2=12, $var3=IN 
delete statement
```

loop 2 - delete query will use the below variable values

```
$var1=1111, $var2=10, $var3=SA 
delete statement
```

loop 3 - delete query will use the below variable values

```
$var1=2222, $var2=11, $var3=EU
delete statement
```

loop 4 - delete query will use the below variable values

```
$var1=3333, $var2=13, $var3=CN 
delete statement
```

Comment: Please make the question clear if you want to know the delete statement or a way to get the values into the variable.

Comment: You'd better have absolute control over your input file: https://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 2):

Use a `while read` loop, setting `$IFS` to a comma to split the lines.

```
while IFS=, read -r var1 var2 var3 rest
do
    echo "delete from table1.test where id=$var1 and code=$var2 and country='$var3'"
done < test.txt | mysql ...
```

Comment: Note that if the file is being modified in the loop (e.g. if the lines are actually being deleted, rather than "delete ..." just being printed), then this will have trouble. Reading from a file as it's being changed is almost never safe.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I don't think the lines are being deleted, I believe that he's using the file to submit delete queries to a database.

Comment: I *think* you're right, but I'm not entirely clear how it's being used so I thought it safer to add a caveat

Answer (score 2):

Another approach rater than looping with bash:

```sh
<input.csv cut -d',' --output-delimiter=' ' -f1,2,3 |
  xargs -l printf 'delete from table1.test where id="%s" and code="%s" and country="%s";\n' >deletes.sql
```

Explanations:

- `<input.csv cut -d',' --output-delimiter=' ' -f1,2,3 |`: extract first 3 comma delimited fields from `input.csv`, and turn them into space delimited arguments.
- `xargs -l printf >deletes.sql`: `xargs` feeds lines of arguments to `printf` to be formatted into SQL statements and writes the output to the `deletes.sql` file.

Or use `awk` to do it all at once:

```sh
awk -F, '{ printf("delete from table1.test where id=\"%s\" and code=\"%s\" and country=\"%s\";\n", $1, $2, $3) }' input.csv >deletes.sql
```

Or with a stand-alone `csv2sql` awk script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S awk -f

BEGIN {
  FS=","
}

{
  printf( "delete from table1.test where id=\"%s\" and code=\"%s\" and country=\"%s\";\n", $1, $2, $3)
}
```

Usage:

```sh
# Make csv2sql executable
chmod +x csv2sql

# Run it
./csv2sql input.csv >output.sql
```

Output generated from sample:

```sql
delete from table1.test where id="1234" and code="12" and country="IN";
delete from table1.test where id="1111" and code="10" and country="SA";
delete from table1.test where id="2222" and code="11" and country="EU";
delete from table1.test where id="3333" and code="13" and country="CN";
delete from table1.test where id="4444" and code="14" and country="US";
```